# retrieving data saved in database one by one when clicking a button

Tags: java

This coding is done in ActionPerformed of btnNext. According to my requirement datas retrieve from database must be displayed one by one on Label of the Frame. But this programming does not give result as per my requirement.

```
try
     {
      Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
      Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:registration");
      Statement stmt=con.createStatement();

      for(int i=1;i<=10;i++)
      {      
      ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select * from question"); 

      while(rs.next())
      {
      Serial_No=rs.getString(2);
        lblSerialNo.setText(Serial_No);
        Question=rs.getString(3);
        lblQuestion.setText(Question);
        Choice1=rs.getString(4);
        radOption1.setText(Choice1);
        Choice2=rs.getString(5);
        radOption2.setText(Choice2);
       Choice3=rs.getString(6);
        radOption3.setText(Choice3);
       System.out.println(Serial_No+"\n"); 
      }
      }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
     System.err.println(ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually when you are setting this way the previous values gets overridden by the new row from the resultset beacause it keeps iterating while resultset has next rows to fetch.

what you can do is get the values store the values in a list and later iterate the list and display the values as required